# Stepped gradient without blur in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I want to achieve the same effect as on [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147180/photoshop-how-to-create-a-stepped-gradient-without-blurred-separation) in Inkscape, how do I do it?
I've searched but doesn't find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a gradient for something like that.

Instead draw a rectangle, duplicate it. Move them apart. Fill with different shades of grey, select both, and do *Extensions > Generate from path > Interpolate between paths*.  Make sure you enable the "Interpolate style" option.

[image]

It is possible to set up a gradient with steps, but you would need to add the stops manually. Basically, make a gradient, add stops, duplicate a stop near each step and move it back to the previous and repeat for all the stops.

[image]